# Selection of value by jQuery

Tags: jquery

In an HTML table I want to select some items, I use jQuery in the following manner:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $("input[id*='chkSelectPackage1']").bind("change",function(){
    var control=$(this).closest("tr");
    var aaaaaaa=control.filter(":nth-child(5)");
  });
});
```

In the HTML table every row has 6 cells, in the 6th cell I have a checkbox and in the selection of this checkbox I want the value inside the 4th cell. How can I do this, I am able to find the closest 'tr' but not the children of this 'tr'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the use of [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var aaaaaaa = control.filter(":nth-child(5)");
```

It should work if you use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), and use the correct index (`nth-child` is 1-indexed):

```
var aaaaaaa = control.find(":nth-child(4)");
```

`filter` looks at the top-level elements within your jQuery object. In your case, there is only one (the `tr`), so that won't work. `find` looks at descendants.

Comment: You Are Right,but i didn,t get the difference between find and filter